# Display value of number of selected options in jQuery multiSelect

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/866557/

What I am trying to do is:
When you click some number of items in the dropdown list, where the words "2 items selected" (in foo div) the number 2 should change to reflect the number of items that are selected.  So if there are 4 items selected, the text should read "4 items selected"

This is what I have tried (as well as other variations):

```
$('#foo').multiselect({
    onChange: function() {
        console.log($('#foo').val());
    }
}); 
<div id="foo"></div>
```

but I am clearly doing it wrong.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

At your end of `.multiSelectElement` and `.multiSelectClose` click function, refresh your item count using code below:

```
$("#foo").html($(".multiSelectElementSelected").length + " item(s) selected.");
```

Comment: Hmm... that shows 0 items selected but when I click on items it does not change the number it just stays on 0

Comment: Nevermind I figured out what you meant and that totally works!